# show loading spinner until all child components inside of a Page have been rendered - Nativescript

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I'm trying to show an activity indicator, when I go from one page to another. The target page contains many components within it, and it takes time to load. that's why I need some way to listen when all the child components are loaded, and at that moment tell my variable isBussy to be false

```javascript
<template>
<StackLayout>
  <ActivityIndicator :busy="isBussy" v-if="isBussy" />
  <StackLayout v-else>
    <Component1 />
    <Component2 />
    <Component3 />
    <Component4 />
  </StackLayout>
<StackLayout>
</template>

<script>

import Component1 from '~/components/Component1'
import Component2 from '~/components/Component2'
import Component3 from '~/components/Component3'
import Component4 from '~/components/Component4'

export default {

  data() {
    return {
      isBussy: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function() {
      // Code that will run only after the
      // entire view has been re-rendered
      this.isBussy = false
    })
  }

}
</script>
```

this code does not work, since once the navigation is indicated from the previous page with:
`@tap="$goto('otherPage', { props: { foo: bar } })"`

it remains stuck on the initial page, and all the components begin to load in the background of the destination page, but without displaying the parent page, changing to this, only when the whole process ends, and never show/hide the activity indicator as expected.

By the way this expected behavior works perfectly when i do request and process them with Promises, then I turn on or off a variable in the state and it works. but I can not replicate that behavior in the navigation between pages and listen to load all the components

#### **EDIT**

Finally I achieved the desired behavior with a little trick I found on the internet

```javascript
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.isBussy = false
    }, 500)
  },
```

this causes that the rendering of all the children components is delayed only a little, so that the activity indicator is shown, but not too much to produce that none of the components contained in the else block is detected and begin to rendering

Comment: Glad you found something that works for you! Just beware it looks like you’re introducing 500ms of loading time (for all children) just to show the activity indicator

Comment: You could remove v-else and just have child components begin to load if they have a pleasant default loading state, and you could keep what you have with your setTimeout solution.  This would not add delay to children loading. Also I’m not sure what stackoverflow guidelines are, but you may want to update the Question title since you weren’t seeking for what you asked for

Answer (score 2):

There are two main ideas to understand here I think. I'll describe both.

### 1. General technique to Fetch Data without blocking render

It sounds like you understand this concept at the parent component level but then are asking how to do something very similar for the child components that this page contains.

The way I handle this, is in my component, I have my data default to an isLoading state. Then, in `beforeMount()` or `mounted()`, I perform my asynchronous actions and make necessary changes to my page's data.

**The problem becomes entirely recursive when we look at child components. You want to make sure your child components are rendering and that any long running data fetching that needs to occur within their implementation will simply cause them to re-render once that fetching is complete.**

Here is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/r4o56o3olp
This example uses Nuxt. Aside from the addition fetch() and asyncData() methods, the rest of the Vue lifecycle hooks are the same here.

I use `new Promise` and `setTimeout` to demonstrate an operation that would use promises and be asynchronous. (e.g. `axios.get(..)`)

The About page loads, and the `beforeMount()` lifecycle hook performs the asynchronous fetching in a way that doesn't block the page from rendering.

I use the `beforeMount()` hook because, according to here ( https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/ ), it is the first lifecycle hook that we have access to once the page's data is reactive. (So modifying `this.myDataProp` would trigger a re-render if `{{ myDataProp }}` was used in the template).

I also included a child component where I purposely made its data take twice as long to load. Since I again, am letting the component render immediately, and *then* I handle the fetching/updating of data in an appropriate lifecycle hook, I can manage when the end-user perceives a page to be loaded.

In my working example, the `LongLoadingComponent` did the same exact technique as the About page.

Once you see how to use `beforeMount()` or `mounted()` to fetch data and then update state, I think the trick is to take a moment and really think about the default state of your component. When it first renders, what should the user see before any of it's data fetching/long-running operations are completed?

Once you determine what your default (not yet loaded) component should look like, try getting that to render on your screen, and secondarily add in the logic that fetches and updates state data.

### 2. Listening for when a Child Component is finished rendering from a parent component

This makes use of the above technique, but includes the usage of the `updated()` hook and emitting a *custom event* ( https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html
)

If you really want to *listen* for when your child components are finished rendering, you can `$emit` a custom event in your `updated()` hook. Perhaps something like this (in one of your child components)

```
if (this.dataLoaded) { this.$emit('loadedAndRendered') }
```

So when the child's async operations are done, it can flip it's `dataLoaded` property to true. If `dataLoaded` is used in the child's `<template>` somewhere, then the component should re-render (for it's "finished" state). When the child re-renders, the `updated()` hook should trigger. (again, see: https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/ ) I included the `if (this.dataLoaded)` part just to handle case where `updated()` hook might be called during intermediate data updates. (We only want to emit `loadedAndRendered` event if child is *finished* loading data/updating.)

### 3. Other caveats about universal nuxt applications

It wasn't until after I wrote this answer that I realized you aren't using Nuxt. However I'm adding this in case other Nuxt users happen to come across this.

I'm adding this section just because it took some focused hands-on time for me to wrap my head around. A Nuxt Universal Application does both server-side and client-side rendering. Understanding when something renders on the client vs when it was rendered on the server was a little difficult for me at first. In the working example I linked above, when you visit the about page you can also see if that component was fetched from the server or if it was just rendered by the client.

I'd recommend playing with a Page's fetch() and asyncData() methods and see how it impacts when certain things render on your screen. ( https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch/ ) ( https://nuxtjs.org/api/ ). Seeing what these methods *are* useful for helps me also identify what they are *not* useful for.

If you're using a Vuex store, I'd recommend seeing what happens when you refresh a page or use  instead of a  to navigate between pages. (Seeing something like the SSR schema diagram can be helpful here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide#schema )

..I have yet to fully appreciate the details of the bundling and delivery behavior that Webpack provides for a Universal Nuxt app (See right side of diagram here:  https://medium.freecodecamp.org/universal-application-code-structure-in-nuxt-js-4cd014cc0baa )

Comment: To add on to this, if you are looking for a solution that works with Vuex store, this still works.

Instead of modifying local component state you'll likely be committing store mutations or dispatching store actions. Follow the same technique, just read from store state and make any data changes through Vuex mutations.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I think it does not solve my problem completely.
Since if I have 20 components, I do not want to go for each one defining, "I'm ready" in its mounted.
I can not simulate loading components with promises as if it were a request.
And it is a Nativescript application
For the rest, I did not specify in my question that I can not use vue-router to make a simple router.beforeEach () since it is currently unsupported

Comment: I hear you, just curious, is it really that bad to just emit ‘imReady’ event or similar for the child components you’re loading? You’ll just have one listener in the parent counting the events (would expect 20 events for 20 child components if you’re tracking).

Comment: Other option is accessing data through $refs but I think emitting events is the recommended way of doing the same thing: accessing child state data.      As for your page rendering blocking issue... any chance you want to try explaining more about what you’re trying to accomplish and what did or didn’t work for you? I may be able to spot what’s going on then